# Why Java compiler does not provide caller's line number information?

Tags: java, logging, javac, line-numbers

C# has these really nice compiler annotations: `CallerMemberName`, `CallerFilePath` `CallerLineNumber` which (as names say) caller's member name, file path and line number. This makes things like logging source code line numbers so easy (and efficient).

Before Java 9's StackWalker, it seems the only option is to use `getStackTrace()` which is very expensive. Why it took Java so long to include a solution?

Also, how efficient is Java 9's StackWalker compared with a simple compile time computed parameter? I guess difference is huge... which begs the question: why Java *can't* have compile time computed parameters?

Comment: Java (originally called Oak) was (originally) for cable tv boxes. Why would an embedded device (early versions of Java ran with, if you were ***really*** lucky 16 megabytes of ram) need that feature? Basically, you are looking at it the wrong way round. The world was a different place when Java was designed. And the C# designers were working towards very different goals than the original Java designers, and they had the benefit of Java already existing to be studied and if Visual J++ hadn't triggered a lawsuit perhaps things might have gone **very *differently*** in the 2000s. Who can say.

Comment: *"Why it took Java so long to include a solution?"* Because there was not enough people lobbying for it.

Comment: What good is a line number when logging?  Surely your logging statements are written to provide useful information, regardless of the exact line number, right?  `logger.fine(() -> "Preparing to write " + file);` tells me what I need to know.  A line number adds little value.

Comment: IMHO, line numbers in logs are great time savers (I'd say C/C++, C# and Golang designers think the same). In any case, I understand the arguments that refer to constrained resources. But that doesn't seem hold: C has such feature for eons!

Comment: Really? C can tell you the *caller’s* line number? Not really. Can you explain, how a compile-time computed information about the runtime caller is supposed to work?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I meant C has __FILE__ and __LINE__ markers which preprocessor replaces with source file and number.